# FlaskForm Validation Code: checking if a user already exists or not

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

So I was following Corey Schafer's Flask tutorial when I came to the part about checking if a username or email is already used while registering for an account. I cannot for the life of me understand how this code works, I guess its because I'm new to Python and Flask but still it shouldn't be this confusing.

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):

    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4,                                  
    max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password_confirm = PasswordField('Confirm password', validators=[DataRequired(),EqualTo('password')])             
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')


def validate_username(self, username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
    if user:
        raise ValidationError('That username is taken. Please choose 
        another.')

def validate_email(self, email):
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
    if user:
        raise ValidationError('That email is taken. Please choose another.')
```

So, the specific part that I don't understand are the two functions in the RegistrationForm class: Firstly, how do both of the functions know what username and email is? For example if I changed the 'username' and 'email' arguments in the function definitions to something like 'u_n' and 'e_mail' and then ran the query with 'u_n.data' and 'e_mail.data', the code still works.
Secondly if I'm to rename the functions to anything else the code stops working and I don't understand why?

I know the answer to this cannot be too complicated but this has annoyed me so much. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you import User?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am going to explain this thoroughly, so bear with me as I will answer your specific questions at the end, to make sure you fully understand how all the pieces work together.

Your form definition is given with this chunk of code:

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)])                           
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password_confirm = PasswordField('Confirm password', validators=[DataRequired(),EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

This is what creates the *form's UI on the screen* and **ultimately what the user sees when they're signing up**. This form creation is accomplished with the `flask_wtf` library, and is rendered within an html page with the help of `Jinja2`. `Jinja2` is a *templating engine* that Python can leverage to serve server-side pages with dynamic data. *Now what do the variables within this form definition mean?* I.e. **[username, email, password, confirm_password, submit]**  well these are *references to the form's fields*. For example, when the user typed in their information to sign up for an account on your site, the username they used is accessed by referencing the `form.username.data` field. Similarly, to get the password they used, to sign up with, you have to reference the `form.password.data` field and so on and so forth... The validation functions: `validate_username(...)` and `validate_email(..)` are class methods you created on your `RegistrationForm(FlaskForm)` class to validate the **uniqueness** of a user's `email` and `username` when he/she submits their account details by clicking the `Sign Up` button. If another user is *already using this username or email an error will be thrown*. *So how is this accomplished?* This **validation is assisted by your model definitions** created within your `models.py` file:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

These models are leveraging `flask-sqlalchemy`, a wrapper around `sqlalchemy`, to make **queries within your tables**, in this example your `user` table. `Sqlalchemy` is a *Python SQL toolkit and ORM* that makes it easy to *submit SQL queries as well as map objects to table definitions and vice versa.* So `user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()` is leveraging your `User` model definition, which has been setup with `flask-sqlalchemy`, to query your `user` table to see if anyone else has signed up with that username. The `from flaskblog.models import User` is the import statement which is allowing you to use your `User` model to query your `user` table from within your form definition file. Furthermore, the reason we can use `username.data` instead of having to use `form.username.data` is because this is an object method within your `RegistrationForm` so we have direct access to the username and email form fields.

Now to answer your questions:

1. "Why if I change the 'username' and 'email' arguments in the function definitions to something like 'u_n' and 'e_mail' and ran the query with 'u_n.data' and 'e_mail.data' does the code still works"

**Answer**: These are just **function parameter variables and can be named however you see fit** since you're passing the username (or email) form field directly into the function through the function declaration. i.e. **`validate_<field_name>`**

2. "If I to rename the functions to anything else the code stops working and I don't understand why?"

**Answer**:
Your validation methods have to follow the **`validate_<field_name>`** convention specified within `flask-wtf` In your example, your form fields are: **[username, email, password, confirm_password, submit]** so your validation methods would have to be: `validate_username(...)`, `validate_email(...)`, `validate_password(...)`, etc... If you want to have a different validation method name you would also have to correspondingly rename your form fields appropriately.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation really cleared up a lot for me! Bless!

Comment: np, glad it helped

Comment: +1 thanks for the explanation. For anyone interested these are called in-line validators. Read more here https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/forms/#in-line-validators-and-filters

Comment: +1 thanks... You made my day. I screwed up the syntax of validate_<field> rule and broke my mind trying to figure out why the validation didn't work.